How should I handle interviewing with two companies for the same project?
I am a software engineer and looking for the next step on my career. I had a first interview with company A and they are keen on going to next steps. They also told me that I will work for another company's project without naming the other company and they told me the salary budget is up to X. Then I had a call with company B, they also told me they like my profile and they give me about X to X +200$ net per month.
And now the surprise. I found out in the assessment of company B that it will get checked from the Tech lead of company A.
Both of them seem pretty good. What should I consider to decide how to proceed?

"I found out in the assessment of company B that it will get checked from the Tech lead of company A." - What exactly do you mean by this statement? Are you simply saying Company B is a subcontractor for Company A?

"How would you proceed" is off-topic for this site's guidelines. If you've got concrete questions on what this means or if there are any conflicts, that would be on topic.

@Donald company B is let's say a bigger one and gets help from company A which is a smaller software house, so the technical interviews are hosted by company A.

@AzureBlossomTree - If Company A is a subcontractor to Company B that explains the salary delta. The subprime employee only makes more if they work on multiple projects.

Before this progresses much further, you need to let both entities know that there's been a potential conflict.  If you are submitted to the end client by both, you are likely to be rejected outright because the end client won't want to get involved in any tug-of-war (read: LITIGATION) between the entities that are trying to submit you.  Such situations are exhausting, expensive, and obviously detract from the main line of business.
Do not try to be slick about this and manipulate things so that you end up with the one that pays more.  You may be blacklisted by both sides.  Reputation means a lot in consulting, so it's important to not burn bridges.

I phoned hr from company A, told them the situation and they really appreciated. They told me they will sync to find best solution for both three sides. Thank you

Isn't B the end client, and A is a contractor that they're hiring? I don't see any mention of 2 contractors working for a third party.

@Barmar A, B and the OP

@mmmmmm My question is about "the two entities that are trying to submit you". Submit the OP to who?
